# Why flatpak installed applications don't respect Mint Dark-Y theme?

Tags: apt, flatpak

I have this issue when I install some applications in Mint where they don't respect Y-Dark theme that I use.
They turn to dark mode normally when I install them with apt, but not when I install them with flatpak.

Examples: Filezilla, Meld, Eclipse. Eclise does change to dark when I change to dark mode but it keeps lots of white outlines.

I've tried enabling all options in Flatseal but it still didn't work.

Anyone has any idea why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure *why*, but sometimes, after changing the system theme, it fixes itself if you run `flatpak update`. I know that some Flatpak applications do not support custom themes, but in those cases, I personally use [stylepak](https://github.com/refi64/stylepak).

Comment: Flatpak update didin't change anything. Result: "Looking for updates…Nothing to do.". When I tried to run `stylepak install-system` I got a "GPG verification enabled, but no signatures found" error. As I don't know how to solve it, I opened an issue on stylepak's github project: github.com/refi64/stylepak/issues/28 Do you know how to handle this by the way ?

Comment: Seems like I forgot to answer you, sorry. Do you have GPG enabled? If yes, do you have any GPG-keys?

Comment: When I created this question I didn't have. Recently I installed it to create some keys for a jwt feature I'm working in a project. But AFAIU, if I haven't installed it at the time of writting the question I think the correct answer would be no. But if you need me to do something with gpg then the answer is yes.

Comment: Have you tried re-running stylepak now that you have a key to see if it works? If you still get the same error, you might have to unlock your GPG key first. Tbh, I don't think this is an issue with stylepak, rather flatpak itself.

Comment: I think I didn't explained correctly. I created a pair of non-offical GPG keys for a project of mine. Not anyhting relevant to stylepak/flatpak. How do I get and unlock these keys ?